# How to split a string if it contains period (.)?

Tags: c#, winforms, string

I am taking numerical input from a text box. I want to check

```
if(textBox1.Text.Contains("."))
```

like 55.37

then split the string in two parts/strings.

1. First part before period (55)
2. Second part after the period (37)

Comment: What if the user enters a value with more than one period character?

Comment: So split it?  Are you asking how to split a string?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this:

```
string[] ret = textBox1.Text.Split('.');
```

Then you can do

```
if (ret.Length != 2) // error ?!?
```

ret[0] is integer part
ret[1] is fractional part

Comment: @Reniuz: I've already changed it, maybe you saw my "still editing" version ;) Anyway thanks!! :)

Answer (score 4):

use string.Split method

```
   string[] a = textBox1.Text.Split('.'); 


   string b = a[0];
   string c = a[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var splitted = textBox1.Text.Split('.');
```

The result will be an array of strings. In your sample, the array will have 2 strings, 55 and 37.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!textBox1.Text.Contains('.'))
    return;

var parts = textBox1.Text.Split('.')
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I like the textBox1.Text.Contains('.') approach. I'd have done what Marco did and check the length. Just shows there are many ways to skin that cat.

Comment: Thanks! I edited it to represent my intent a bit more, you could bail out early if it doesn't contain a '.', which enables the code after the if-statement to "focus" on the important parts.

Answer (score 2):

In case there is a chance your code will be executed on OS with non-windows localization please use:

```
var separators = new[] {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator};
var parts = textBox1.Text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

It looks too verbose but it may be hard to understand why your code works on your machine (with dev environment) but don't on customers.

Answer (score 0):

use Split method

```
dim s as string = textbox1.text
s.split(".")
```

Comment: Format your code as code (CTRL+K or the editor button) so people can read it better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
textBox1.Text.Split('.')
```

Comment: My question got 2 down-votes, but at-least many of you corrected their own syntax. Credit goes to Macro. :D

Comment: I am not getting why double quotes won't compile, ex: textBox1.Text.Split("."), can someone please shed some light on this ?